# ¿Y si ponemos nuestros perfiles en español?

Tags: discusión, perfil, idiomas

En el sitio somos bastante exigentes con que toda publicación esté en español, y continuamente corregimos traducciones de la interfaz... -Y está perfecto que así sea.

Sin embargo, muchos de nosotros trajimos texto en inglés en **la descripción del perfil**. ¿Y si empezamos a dar el ejemplo en todo sentido?

Por supuesto, esto no es obligatorio de ninguna manera, simplemente es una invitación a hacerlo.

---

Nota: para quienes no sepan, al editar el perfil, en el pie permite guardar los cambios para toda la red de SE o para 1 sola comunidad:

[image: Guardar cambios solo para esta comunidad | Guardar cambios y copiarlos a todas las comunidades de Stack Exchange]

permitiendo que sólo se grabe en SOes.

Comment: No sabía que el perfil se podía guardar sólo para una comunidad. Buen apunte.

Comment: @JordiCastilla No fue por publicidad, si fuera así, todo Meta estaría inundado de mensajes como ese... En fin, borré mi respuesta ya que fue incómodo para al menos 8 personas, por el hecho de no estar relacionada con la pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bien pensado eso de poner el perfil en español, se me había pasado por alto.

Pero yo lo voy a añadir, dejándolo también en inglés. SO es un sitio primariamente en inglés y es muy posible que un angloparlante llegue al perfil a través de SOes, no le quiero poner dificultades artificiales con un perfil exclusivo en español.

Comment: Tener ambos es otra opción. Cada uno elige lo que quiere, por supuesto. El punto es tener el texto en español de cualquiera de las dos formas. ¡Gracias por sumarte a la propuesta!